# React Native 0.45.1 : RCTBundleURLProvider.h” file not found error in TeamCity

Tags: ios, react-native, continuous-integration, teamcity

I am doing the teamcity configuration for React Native IOS project and have completed the configuration partially. I am stuck with the below error

```
[CompileC]
/Users/developer/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/
work/604db77ecbb3cbg9/ios/SampleApp/AppDelegate.m:2:9:
fatal error: 'React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h' file not found
[16:56:50][CompileC] #import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
[16:56:50][CompileC]         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[16:56:50][CompileC] 1 error generated.
```

The app works fine independetly when we run in xcode or through terminal with react native comman but fails while doing the build in team city. Please let me know if anyone have faced this issue and resolved it. Would appreciate the help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: show your build steps

Comment: Build Steps are as follow 1)npm install - which will install all dependencies from package.json 2)react-native link - which will link all assets and modules 3) Xcode project - For now build is target based and platform is Simulator. Hope this helps